# OSX: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode8, dylib

While working on update to my project (XCode 8.3) I faced the following crash:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libfmod.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/IK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PathOfLight_OSX-fibtvsfsodlsmdhggpkzuifkihzq/Build/Products/Debug/PathOfLight_fullAppStore.app/Contents/MacOS/PathOfLight_fullAppStore
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/IK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PathOfLight_OSX-fibtvsfsodlsmdhggpkzuifkihzq/Build/Products/Debug/PathOfLight_fullAppStore.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libfmod.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Users/IK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PathOfLight_OSX-fibtvsfsodlsmdhggpkzuifkihzq/Build/Products/Debug/PathOfLight_fullAppStore.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libfmod.dylib'
```

I tried many advices from the similar topics:
 - Downloaded new Apple WWDR certificate
 - Rebooted computer, cleared project and derived data several times
 - Changed and cleared **Runpath Search Paths**
 - Checked, that dylib exists in Frameworks in the bundle

Note again, this was a working project, that was submitted to the store about a year ago.

I'll appreciate any ideas how to make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got it! Provisioning profile for the game, installed on my machine, was expired. When looked into package content for another time I installed (double clicked) *embedded.provisionprofile* included into it and all worked!

Answer (score 0):

My issue also was the same like you, embedded.provisionprofile. After double clicking and installing the profile, it worked.